# Angular Universal not giving performance improvement as expected on Google pagespeed insights

Tags: angular, angular7, angular-universal

This is the result that I am getting when I am doing only server side rendering (without bootstraping client side). This means the page served cannot be interacted with as no js execution takes place on browser.

`First Contentful Paint: 0.6 s    First Meaningful Paint: 0.6 s
Speed Index: 0.6 s               First CPU Idle: 1.5 s
Time to Interactive: 1.7 s       Max Potential First Input Delay:140 ms`

**Overall score: 99**

---

This is the result that I am getting when I am doing rendering using Angular universal and preboot (server side rendering + client side rendering). Page is fully interactive.

`First Contentful Paint: 0.6 s    First Meaningful Paint: 0.6 s
Speed Index: 2.5 s               First CPU Idle: 2.6 s
Time to Interactive: 3.3 s       Max Potential First Input Delay:160 ms`

**Overall score: 75**

---

It is clearly evident that Speed Index, First CPU Idle and Time to Interactive were badly hampered when I tried to execute javascript on client side as well.

I am not sure how to decrease this. Using Angular Universal and preboot.

When I am not using Angular Universal (only client side rendering) even then the scores are better than using server side rendering + client side rendering. I require server side rendering for SEO purposes.

What could be the issue?

Comment: Check this thread: https://github.com/GoogleChrome/lighthouse/issues/10845. And this one back from 2018: https://github.com/GoogleChrome/lighthouse/issues/4578. It seems like because of re-hydration Angular Universal gets its core metrics delayed resulting in a poor scores.

Answer (score 1):

Since 2019 google prefer TTI to FCP..
This is the problem, the solution i did not found.

Here some tips i read just now

https://code101.net/code-101/replacing-angular-with-plain-javascript-modules